# Absolute value of a complex number with a arbitrary basis

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value, euler-mascheroni-constant

I want to calculate the square of the absolute value of a complex number $x^{ia}$, with $x$ and $a$ being real while $i$ is the imaginary number:

$$\left|x^{ia}\right|^2=?.$$

I have trouble because the basis is not the Euler constant $e$, but an arbitrary $x$. So, the first approach would be to rewrite it like:

$$x^{ia}=r\cdot e^{ia},$$

but how can I find $r$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As
$$x=e^{ln(x)}$$
Therefore
$$x^{ia}=e^{ln(x)\cdot ia}=e^{i\cdot ln(x)a}$$
So
$$r=1$$
and your phase is different from what you thought.

Answer (score 1):

For real $x\gt0$, we usually take $\log(x)$ to be real as well. Since $a$ is also real, we have $\log(x^{ia})=ia\log(x)$ is pure imaginary. That means that
$$
\left|x^{ia}\right|=\left|1\cdot e^{ia\log(x)}\right|=1
$$
Therefore, $r=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be very carefull with the notation $x^a$ if $x$ is allowed to be an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{C}$. It's natural to define $x^a$ via $$
  x^a = \exp(a\cdot\ln x)
$$
but that leaves the *natural logarithm* $\ln x$ to be defined for arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{C}$.

Now, since the exponential function is not one-to-one over the complex numbers (observe that $\exp(x) = \exp(x + i2\pi k)$ for all $x$) multiple such definitions are possible. Assume that $\ln_1$ is one possible definition of a *natural logarithm* over $\mathbb{C}$, and $\ln_2$ another, with $$
  \ln_2(x) = i2\pi + \ln_1(x).
$$

Then these two definitions then yiel, in general, different values for $x^a$ if $a \notin\mathbb{N}$, since $$\begin{align}
  x^a = \exp(a\ln_1(x)) \neq exp(a\ln_1(x))\cdot\underbrace{\exp(i2\pi a)}_{\neq 1} 
  &= \exp(a\ln_1(x) + i2\pi a) \\
  &= \exp(a(\ln_1(x) + i2\pi)) \\
  &= \exp(a\ln_2(x)).
\end{align}$$